# Kubectl. No environment variables are found in the service

Tags: python, django, kubernetes, minikube

I built an API with django, celery and redis. I deployed the API in minikube an add some secrets to the cluster with:

```
kubectl create secret generic my-secret-storage \
--from-literal=AZURE-STORAGE-ACCOUNT-NAME='account_name' \
--from-literal=AZURE-STORAGE-ACCOUNT-KEY='account_key' \
--from-literal=AZURE-STORAGE-CONTAINER-NAME='container_name'
```

And I build the deployd and the service in this way:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-consulta-acciones
  labels:
    app: api-consulta-acciones
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api-consulta-acciones
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api-consulta-acciones

    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api-consulta
          image: my_image
          args:
            - sh
            - -c
            - |-
              python3 ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
      
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000

          env:
            - name: AZURE-STORAGE-ACCOUNT-NAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: my-secret-storage
                  key: AZURE-STORAGE-ACCOUNT-NAME

            - name: AZURE-STORAGE-ACCOUNT-KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: my-secret-storage
                  key: AZURE-STORAGE-ACCOUNT-KEY

            - name: AZURE-STORAGE-CONTAINER-NAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: my-secret-storage
                  key: AZURE-STORAGE-CONTAINER-NAME

        - name: celery
            # Celery deployd

        - name: celery-beat
            # Celery-beat deployd

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-consulta-svc
  labels:
    app: api-consulta-svc
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: "8000"
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: api-consulta-acciones
```

If I get into the container `api-consulta-acciones -c api-consulta`, I can confirm that the secret variables were created:

```
# Inside the pod
>>> import os
>>> os.environ
environ({'AZURE-STORAGE-ACCOUNT-NAME': 'account_name', 
         'AZURE-STORAGE-CONTAINER-NAME': 'container_name', 
         'AZURE-STORAGE-ACCOUNT-KEY': 'account_key', ..... })
```

However, the problem is when I use the API in the service and try to access the secret variables. It throws me the error that the variable is not found in the environment:

```
File \"/api-acciones/core/services.py\", line 61, in action_write_parquet
account_name = os.environ[cfg.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME]
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py\", line 675, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'AZURE-STORAGE-ACCOUNT-NAME'
```

Comment: Is there error coming from the main container? `env:` settings apply to only the container they are in, not all of them. As a side note, probably don't run celery and beat in one pod like this, make separate deployments for each.

Comment: It looks like perhaps there may be inconsistencies with underscores and dashes based on the error message? I'd suggest using underscores in the secret keys and in the os.environ refs. Also make sure that the secret exists by calling:
`kubectl get secrets --namespace <ns>`

Comment: @HighwayofLife, no, is not a problem of underscores and dashes. And also, I checked that the secrets exists with `kubectl get secrets`